# Can anyone explain why foreach worked but not map

Tags: perl, hash, dictionary, exists

I tried to put key-value pairs at %hash1 if key exists in %hash
There is one element in array for which there is no entry at %hash
ex: @array = (1,2,3,4,5); #there is no hash entry for key 1 at %hash

So I thought map would do the job and I will get 4 keys in my new hash i.e. %hash1 but it gives 5 keys. At the same time I tried foreach and it worked. I was in delusion that we can replace foreach using map, but this case made me to think.
Can anyone explain, where my logic goes wrong?

```
#Method 1. Comment it while using Method 2
%hash1 = map { $_=>$hash{$_}  if(exists $hash{$_}) } @array;

# Method 2. Comment whole loop while using method 1
foreach (@array){
    $hash1{$_} = $hash{$_} if(exists $hash{$_});
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is that your `map` expression returns <strike>`undef`</strike> a false value for the first element in `@array`. <strike>And that gets stringified to an empty string as it's being used as a hash key.</strike> *(In the comments Borodin points out that this explanation is incorrect. In fact the empty string comes from the false value that is returned from `exists` when the key is "1")*

You might get a better idea of what is doing on if you a) turn on `strict` and `warnings` and b) use `Data::Dumper` to display the hash once you've created it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Data::Dumper;

my @array = (1 .. 5);
my %hash = ( 2 => 'two', 3 => 'three', 4 => 'four', 5 => 'five' );

my %hash1 = map { $_=>$hash{$_}  if(exists $hash{$_}) } @array;

say Dumper \%hash1;
```

That shows that you end up with a hash like this:

```
$ ./hash 

Odd number of elements in hash assignment at ./hash line 12.
$VAR1 = {
          '' => 2,
          'three' => 4,
          'five' => undef,
          'two' => 3,
          'four' => 5
        };
```

You are generating a list with an odd number of elements. And that doesn't make a happy hash.

When you're building a hash you need to ensure that you have an even number of elements. So when you're using `map` you need to return either zero or two elements for each iteration. So you need something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Data::Dumper;

my @array = (1 .. 5);
my %hash = ( 2 => 'two', 3 => 'three', 4 => 'four', 5 => 'five' );

my %hash1 = map { exists $hash{$_} ? ($_ => $hash{$_}) : () } @array;

say Dumper \%hash1;
```

Note that we explicitly return an empty list when a key isn't found in the first hash.

```
$ ./hash2
$VAR1 = {
          '4' => 'four',
          '3' => 'three',
          '2' => 'two',
          '5' => 'five'
        };
```

Comment: Very quick and very much accurate.

Comment: Your explanation about `undef` being stringified to a null string is *wrong*. The null strings you are seeing are the values of `exists $hash{$_}` for non-existent keys. `undef` won't be converted to a null string without some `Use of uninitialized value` warning noise.

Answer (score 4):

[map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) will always return what you put in its code block. So the return value for

```
%hash1 = map { $_=>$hash{$_}  if(exists $hash{$_}) } @array;
```

will be `$_=>$hash{$_}` when `$hash{$_}` exists and `""` if it doesn't exist.

What you probably wanted to write:

```
my %hash1 = map { exists($hash{$_}) ? ($_ => $hash{$_}) : () }
```

Answer (score 3):

The block of a `map` call is evaluated for every value in the supplied list, and the value returned by the block is the value of the last expression evaluated.

Your `map` statement

```
my %hash1 = map { $_ => $hash{$_}  if (exists $hash{$_}) } @array
```

is equivalent to

```
my %hash1 = map {
  if (exists $hash{$_}) {
    $_ => $hash{$_}
  }
} @array
```

so first of all the expression `exists $hash{$_}` is evaluated. Then, if it is true, `$_ => $hash{$_}` is evaluated.

The last-evaluated expression is therefore `$_ => $hash{$_}` if the test succeeds, which is what you want, but if the test fails the block returns the value of `exists $hash{$_}`.

`exists` returns either `1` or `""` for true or false, so the elements in `@array` which don't appear as a key of `%hash` result in a single empty string in the list that `map` returns.

It is easier to see the result of a `map` if you assign it to an array. That way you avoid `Odd number of elements in hash assignment` warnings and the automatic assignment of an `undef` hash value.

If you write instead

```
my @arr = map { $_ => $hash{$_}  if (exists $hash{X}) } @array;
```

(i.e. the test always *fails*) the result is the same as that of

```
my @arr = map { exists $hash{X} } @array;
```

or just

```
("", "", "", "")
```

The way to write this using `map` is to use the conditional operator so as to return an empty list if the condition fails

```
my %hash1 = map { exists $hash{$_} ? ( $_ => $hash{$_} ) : () } @array
```

I trust you don't need an explanation of why your `foreach` loop works?

I believe there is a case for `return` being valid inside all blocks just as it is allowed in subroutines. `wantarray` is already valid here, and it is a specific restriction that forbids blocks in general to both exit and return an explicit value.

Answer (score 2):

```
my %hash1 = map { ( $_ => $hash{$_} ) if exists($hash{$_}) } @array;
```

is the same thing as

```
my %hash1 = map { exists($hash{$_}) and ( $_ => $hash{$_} ) } @array;
```

Consider what happens when `exists($hash{$_})` is false. A single value (`dualvar(0,"")` aka "a false value") is returned when none should be. You could either change the expression to return an empty list when `exists` is false

```
my %hash1 = map { exists($hash{$_}) ? ( $_ => $hash{$_} ) : () } @array;
```

or you could move the filtering out of the `map`

```
my %hash1 = map { $_ => $hash{$_} } grep { exists($hash{$_}) } @array;
```

Comment: Nice combination of map and grep :D. Thanks